# VBA Match ignores my range parameter and returns wrong value

Tags: vba, match

```
fnd = "MultistateIndicator1.1.St_Caption"

'find the row with the text to change
nRowSavedRecord = Application.Match(fnd, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1027:D6000"), 0)
```

Will return a value like `8`or `102` when those rows are clearly outside the range of `D1027:D6000` plus here is the match it thinks it found:

Looked for:  `MultistateIndicator1.1.St_Caption`

and Match found: `EnablePushButton.1.St_Caption` (in Column D row 8)

I have `0` in the parameter so it finds exact match.

Answer (score 1):

The row number returned by `Match` is relative to the first row of the source range, starting with `1`.
The value of `8` represents the row `1027 + 8 - 1`, which is `Range("D1027:D6000").Cells(8)`.

Answer (score 1):

`WorksheetFunctions.Match()` returns a relative position. You might want to look at cell `D1034` for the found value.